# I want to calculate the total count of false in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

For example consider collection

```json
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    listname: "Work",
    listitems: [
      {
        todo: "Swiming",
        isCompleted: "false"
      },
      {
        todo: "Cycling",
        isCompleted: "true"
      },
      {
        todo: "Gym",
        isCompleted: "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    listname: "Home",
    listitems: [
      {
        todo: "Playing",
        isCompleted: "false"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So I want to find the `true` values in work list which is Completed for eg: `completedTask : 2`

So how can I do it I have tried using aggregate but I am not pro in mongodb

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways, for example using `$filter` in a `$project` stage:

With this query:

- First `$match` by the `listname` you want.
- Then use `$filter` to create the field `listitems` with value filtered. In this case will be add to the list those values where `isCompleted` is equal to `true`.
- And last use '$size' to get the size of the list.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "listname": "Work"
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "listitems": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$listitems",
        "as": "list",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [
            "$$list.isCompleted",
            "true"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "completedTask": {
      "$size": "$listitems"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TMv7PWr_EUw)

Or using `$unwind` and `$group`:

- `$match` the list you want
- Deconstructe the array
- `$match` again by `isCompleted` equal to `true`
- And `$group` using `$sum` to get the total.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "listname": "Work"
  }
},
{
  "$unwind": "$listitems"
},
{
  "$match": {
    "listitems.isCompleted": "true"
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "totalTask": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vXZ9Uzi-UTs)

Comment: insted of making group i can also use count  like this but thanx for the solution

db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "listname": "Work"
  }
},
{
  "$unwind": "$listitems"
},
{
  "$match": {
    "listitems.isCompleted": "true"
  }
},
{
  "$count": "ger"
})

Answer (score 1):

The following aggregation work

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      totalCompleted: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$listitems",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.isCompleted",
                "true"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UTama133k9p)**

Answer (score 1):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `listitems.isCompleted` array
- `$size` to get total elements from above filters result
- `$group` by null and `$sum` total count

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      completedTask: {
        $sum: {
          $size: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$listitems.isCompleted",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this", "true"] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gLLTVEmjNOl)